Laravel sail + Portainer
Всем привет, использую laravel sail, есть задача развернуть мой проект через Portainer - в докере я новичок и не совсем имею знания и опыт.
У меня есть docker.composer.yml файл
services:
laravel.test:
    build:
        context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: sail-8.3/app
    extra_hosts:
        - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-8080}:80'
        - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
    environment:
        WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
        LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html'
    networks:
        - sail
    depends_on:
        - pgsql
        - redis
        - mailpit
pgsql:
    image: 'postgres:15'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
    environment:
        PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
        POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
    volumes:
        - 'sail-pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/pgsql/create-testing-database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test:
            - CMD
            - pg_isready
            - '-q'
            - '-d'
            - '${DB_DATABASE}'
            - '-U'
            - '${DB_USERNAME}'
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    volumes:
        - 'sail-redis:/data'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test:
            - CMD
            - redis-cli
            - ping
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
mailpit:
    image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
        - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    networks:
        - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-pgsql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local

Я загружаю его в stack в portainer, он у меня выдаёт ошибку
failed to deploy a stack: time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"PWD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"WWWUSER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"WWWGROUP\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"DB_DATABASE\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"DB_USERNAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"DB_USERNAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." time="2024-04-29T17:57:44Z" level=warning msg="The \"DB_DATABASE\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." laravel.test Pulling laravel.test Error unable to prepare context: path "./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3" not found

Не могу понять в чем дело, можете подсказать? или как мне правильно всё это развернуть?
